# Что делать, когда при обработке события WinForms контрола нужные данные еще не обновились?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, события

Конечно, напрашивается ответ: "используй другое событие", но, к сожалению, я не нашёл подходящий event.
Живой пример из живой программы: есть таблица настроек, у которой есть колонка типа checkbox. Требуется, чтобы при изменении состояния чекбокса, кнопка Save на форме `Enabled = true;`
Проблема заключается в том, что когда вы нажимаете мышкой на checkbox, событие `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` **не вызывается, пока ячейка не потеряет фокус**.  `Cell.Value` ещё хранит прежнее значение и никаких событий обновления данных не возникает. Новое значение хранится в свойстве `Cell.EditedFormattedValue`, но оно появляется там только **после** выполнения всех событий, которые я тестировал.
Напросилось такое решение:

```
private void gridSettings_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    })
    .ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        if (gridSettings.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name ==
            "ColumnIsMandatory")
        {
            var clickedCell = gridSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            object editedValue = clickedCell.EditedFormattedValue;
            object oldValue = clickedCell.Value;
            if (oldValue != null && editedValue != null && (bool) editedValue != (bool) oldValue)
            {
                clickedCell.Value = (bool) editedValue;
                // Событие изменения данных вызвано принудительно
            }
        }
    }, uiScheduler);
}
```

Но оно обладает недостатками в виде запуска `Task` и отфонарного `Thread.Sleep(200);` который не гарантирует, что данные уже обновились. Да и решение топорное, совсем не изящное.

Как бы вы решали такую проблему?

**UPDATE:**
Работающий пример:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridView gridSettings;
    private Button buttonSave;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridSettings = new DataGridView()
        {
            Location = new Point(0,0),
            Size = new Size(200, 200)
        };
        var column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = "ColumnIsMandatory"
        };
        gridSettings.Columns.Add(column);
        gridSettings.Rows.Add(1);
        buttonSave = new Button {Text = "Save", Location = new Point(210, 210), Enabled = false};
        gridSettings.CellValueChanged += (sender, args) => buttonSave.Enabled = true;
        gridSettings.CellClick += gridSettings_CellClick;
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{gridSettings, buttonSave});
    }

    private void gridSettings_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        })
        .ContinueWith(result =>
        {
            if (gridSettings.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name ==
                "ColumnIsMandatory")
            {
                var clickedCell = gridSettings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                object editedValue = clickedCell.EditedFormattedValue;
                object oldValue = clickedCell.Value;
                if (oldValue != null && editedValue != null && (bool)editedValue != (bool)oldValue)
                {
                    clickedCell.Value = (bool)editedValue;
                    // Событие изменения данных вызвано принудительно
                }
                else if (oldValue == null && editedValue != null)
                {
                    clickedCell.Value = (bool)editedValue;
                }
            }
        }, uiScheduler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Никогда не делайте Thread.Sleep в отдельном потоке! Есть же Task.Delay...

Comment: To Pavel Mayorov: Спасибо! Не знал о такой возможности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, вам способ прекрасно работает, даже если из обработчика `CellClick` выкинуть создание тасков. То есть достаточно оставить оператор `if`.

Тем не менее, событие, которое вам нужно - [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
gridSettings.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += GridSettings_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;

private void GridSettings_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Хм... Действительно... Только вот в исходном приложении не заработало почему-то без Task...

Comment: Большое спасибо! С событием CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged работает без всяких Task )